# Mysql: Order of results with "select <fieldname> from" is different to order of results with "select * from"

Tags: mysql

i have a mysql db with a table 'difficulties' with a few records.  If i do "select * from difficulties" i get them back in the order they were added, ordered by primary key id:

```
mysql> select * from difficulties;
+----+-------+-----------+--------+----------+-----------+
| id | value | name      | letter | low_band | high_band |
+----+-------+-----------+--------+----------+-----------+
|  1 |     1 | very_easy | VE     |        1 |         1 | 
|  2 |     2 | easy      | E      |        2 |         5 | 
|  3 |     3 | medium    | M      |        6 |        10 | 
|  4 |     4 | hard      | H      |       11 |        12 | 
|  5 |     0 | na        | NA     |        0 |         0 | 
+----+-------+-----------+--------+----------+-----------+
```

However, if i do "select name from difficulties" i get them back in a different order:

```
mysql> select name from difficulties;
+-----------+
| name      |
+-----------+
| easy      | 
| hard      | 
| medium    | 
| na        | 
| very_easy | 
+-----------+
```

My question is: what determines this order?  Is there any logic to it?  Is it something like "the order the files representing the records happen to be in within the filesystem" or something else that is to all intents and purposes random?

thanks, max

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is correct and by design: **if you don't ask for sorting, the server doesn't bother with sorting** (sorting can be an expensive operation), and it will return the rows in whatever order it sees fit. Without a requested order, the way the records are ordered can even differ from one query to the next (although that's not too likely).

The order is definitely not random - it's just whatever way the rows come out of the query, and as you see, even minor modifications can change this un-order significantly. This "undefined" ordering is implementation dependent, unpredictable and should not be relied upon.

If you want the elements to be ordered, use the `ORDER BY` clause (that's its purpose) - e.g.

```
SELECT name FROM difficulties ORDER BY name ASC;
```

That will always return the result sorted by name, in ascending order. Or, if you want them ordered by the primary key, last on top, use:

```
SELECT name FROM difficulties ORDER BY id DESC;
```

You can even sort by function - if you actually *want* random order, do this (caveat: horrible performance with largish tables):

```
SELECT name FROM difficulties ORDER BY RAND();
```

For more details [see this tutorial](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html) and [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).

Comment: Thanks Piskvor, that all makes sense.  I know about order by, i was just curious about what was going on in this situation.  I guess i mistakenly assumed that returning the records (or fields from the records) in the order in which the records appear in the table would be the easiest/cheapest thing for the dbms to do, and therefore what it would do, but i have nothing to base this assumption on :) cheers, max

Comment: @Max Williams: I'd guess that @a1ex07 is correct there with the covering index (i.e. an index on the `name` column) - is xe? That would make "just read whatever the index has" the cheapest operation when requesting just the `name` column, but not when requesting all columns. See e.g. this for a longer explanation: http://peter-zaitsev.livejournal.com/6949.html

Answer (score 2):

As Piskvor said, MySQL will order the query however it finds most convenient.  To address the "why" part of your question, the different result orders are probably a side effect of different execution plans.  If you have an index on `difficulties`, the second query would  make use of it but the first would not.

Comment: +1 Good point, also illustrates why it's bad to do `SELECT *` - it can force a full table scan (slow)

Answer (score 1):

Without the `ORDER BY` clause, the results are returned in random order. However, it seems logical to me that the easiest (and the fastest) way for db engine to return data as it's stored. So it's why the fist resultset is ordered by PK (no fragmentation, logical order is the same as physical). In the second case I would assume that you have an index on field `name`, and for the query `select name from difficulties` this index is covering, so db engine scans this index, and it's why you see results ordered by `name`. Anyway, you shouldn't rely on such "default" ordering.

Answer (score -2):

`select name from difficulties` should return the values in alphabetical order as it is a text field.
And `select * from difficulties` will return in numeric order i believe. dont hold me to that lol

best thing to do is use `ORDER BY` if you care about what order things are

Comment: That is just factually wrong. Unless you specifically ask for ordering, the SQL server is not required to return the rows in any kind of order. (of course, `ORDER BY` is the way to ask for ordering, that much is true)